# Find and calculate everything using regex

Tags: android, regex

I have many files within my project (Android) that contain simple equations. Nothing more than (-,+,*,/). I am searching of an easier way to calculate everything without me doing it manually 1 by 1. Is there a way to maybe search everything that is an equation such as (some number) * (other number) and just replace it with it's answer?

Comment: which language do you want to use?

Comment: well it's android studio so it's java code, but i don't know if it matters because i want to just change the pure number values which are in the file. Anywhere where there are (100 *100) to convert it to the answer instead of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no "eval" similar function in Java (assuming you are writing in
Java directly into Android Studio), but in this case it might be of some use the [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) so you can evaluate expressions as a Javascript string that will then use the helpful "eval" function:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");
```

Comment: Yes it's java code. I haven't used the ScriptEngine so I am not familiar with the above code but I assume it need all values to be passed to it and changed separately. But i want all the equations to be automatically found and replaced with the answer. Not sure if I am being clear. Sorry if not.